# How to install tint2 on gnome

Tags: command-line, gnome

I am trying to install tint2 on my ubuntu-gnome 15. Here is what I have done:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/killeroid/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C26CCF8E
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tint2
```

(according to [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/how-to-install-and-configure-tint2.html) page)

The last part is:

```
~/.config/tint2
```

but when I run this command I get:

```
bash: /home/ali/.config/tint2: Is a directory
```

When I type `tint2` in my terminal, it runs and everything is OK, but as soon as I close the terminal it closes too.

*How can I have it running all the time?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tint2 is installed, because you have executed the command below

```
sudo apt-get install tint2
```

---

The folder `~/.config/tint2` is only for configuration files.

The default configuration is in

```
/etc/xdg/tint2/tint2rc
```

[image]

---

Create your own configuration with [tintwizard](https://code.google.com/p/tintwizard/downloads/list) (now [here](https://gitlab.com/o9000/tint2)). Save the configuration as `~/.config/tint2/tint2confrc` and start `tint2` with, eg:

```
tint2 -c ~/.config/tint2/tint2confrc
```

---

For a better integration in GNOME use a desktop file and add the desktop file to your autostart configuration.

*Example for a desktop file with the default configuration*

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=tint2
Comment=tint2 panel
Exec=tint2
Icon=taskbar
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 2):

> When I type tint2 in my terminal, it runs and everything is OK, but as
>   soon as I close the terminal it closes too. How can I have it running
>   all the time?

If you want to close the terminal, then you can run this command in background. You can use:

```
nohup tint2 &
```

or

```
tint2 &
disown
```

or

```
(tint2 &)
```

or

when your `tint2` command is running on a terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and run `bg` on terminal. It will send the process to the background. Then type `disown` and then `exit` from terminal.

If your command should run always when you log in, then you have to add it to the list of startup applications:

- Use the Dash to find and open Startup Applications. Alternatively you can press <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and run the `gnome-session-properties` command.
- Click Add and enter `tint2` as the command to be executed at login (name and comment are optional).